# CORS error only when using a URL query string parameter

Tags: javascript, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a `GET` method on a resource using AWS API Gateway, with a URL query string parameter, that isn't required. I have enabled CORS for the resource, and the `OPTIONS` method is present, and working for other authorized API calls.

If I call the `GET` method from the frontend without the string parameter, everything works fine, without issues. When I run a 'test' via the API Gateway Console with a string parameter, everything works fine. If I call the method from the frontend with a string parameter, I get a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'myAPIURL' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Other information about the API:

- It's used to trigger a lambda function that fetches some DynamoDB records
- No other method has a CROS error, but no other methods use a string parameter
- Some methods use a path parameter, and work fine
- Authorization is through Cognito

My frontend API call is as follows:

```
fetchInvoices(strParam){
    const returnedData = null;
    const url = invokeURL + encodeURIComponent("invoicess?invYear=" + strParam);
    fetch(url, { headers: { "Authorization": token } })
        .then(response => { 
        return response.json() 
    })
    .then(jsonData => {
        returnedData = jsonData;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
    return returnedData
}
```

Why is the string parameter causing a CORS error?

Comment: CORS rules are enforced by browsers. They're not intrinsic to HTTP in general. You can fetch from an API all you want from *outside* of a browser context, but inside code loaded from a web page you have to follow browser rules, which insist on the target URL supplying proper CORS headers to allow access from alien domains.

Comment: Also you're using `encodeURIComponent()` incorrectly. The string "invoicess" can be appended to the URL directly. Then, "invYear" and "strParam" should be passed through `encodeURIComponent()` separately (though of course the constant "invYear" doesn't really need it).  That's why the word "component" is in the name of the function.

Comment: I'm going to guess your OPTIONS call is failing because it can't process that URL.

Comment: How about replacing `encodeURIComponent("invoicess?invYear=" + strParam)` with `'invoicess?' + new URLSearchParams({ invYear: strParam }).toString()`

Comment: @moonstar-x, this was correct. and worked perfectly. If you wanted to add as an answer, I'll be happy to mark as correct.

Comment: Alrighty, glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies in the following line:

```js
const url = invokeURL + encodeURIComponent("invoicess?invYear=" + strParam);
```

Let's check an example, let's say that `invokeURL = 'https://example.com/'` and `strParam = '2024'`. Given this, your `url` variable would actually be:

```
https://example.com/invoicess%3FinvYear%3D2024
```

The problem now is that your API Gateway will see `invoicess%3FinvYear%3D2024` as the path of the URL and not `invoicess` which is why you're getting your CORS error.

---

A solution would be to change how you're passing your query parameters:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({ invYear: strParam });
const url = `${invokeURL}invoicess?${params.toString()}`;
```

[`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) already does the URI encoding necessary so you don't have to worry about it.